# Why does this ppid == 1? Am I missing something about fork()?

Tags: c, fork

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    fork();
    fork();
    printf("ppid %d pid %d\n", getppid(), getpid());
    return 0;
}
```

The above code sometimes prints

```
$ ./a.out 
ppid 3389 pid 3883
ppid 3883 pid 3885
ppid 1 pid 3884
ppid 3884 pid 3886
```

Why is process 3884's ppid 1? Doesn't it supposed to be 3883?

Comment: How can it be 3883 when process 3883 returned from main and no longer exists? And if it didn't exit, this would be a good way to make your system non-functional.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'd guess the parent process had already completed running and exited by the time the third child checked for the parent's PID. That would have caused the child to be re-parented under `init`, which has process ID 1.

Comment: This is a great guess :)  I added a `sleep_for` in my code (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23609507/pause-program-execution-for-5-seconds-in-c) question) for longer than it took to run the program.  As long as I can keep the parent around until after all of its children finished executing, ppid never returns as being "1".  Thanks for the enlightenment @jamey-sharp.

Comment: shouldn't the child process get killed as well when the parent process exits? or does it only apply to threads?

Answer (score 3):

Taken from:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2Fgetppid.htm

"The value returned by getppid() is the process ID of the parent process for the calling process. A process ID value of 1 indicates that there is no parent process associated with the calling process."

That printf instruction was executed within the parent process, so it returned 1 because it does not have a parent process.  It's perfectly normal that this was the 3rd line to be printed, since the fork run its process concurrently and no particular order is guarantied.

Comment: I don't think this explains the observed symptom. The original process running `./a.out` should have the shell as its parent.

Answer (score 2):

To build upon Jamey's answer, when a process finishes before the child's execution and exits, the child becomes an orphan i.e. orphan process so the kernel maps that orphan to the init process.

Using wait() makes sure that the parent waits until the child has finished execution.