# Pause program execution for 5 seconds in c++

Tags: c++

I want to pause the execution of c++ program for 5 seconds. In android Handler.postDelayed has the required functionality what I am looking for. Is there anything similar to that in c++?

Comment: #include <unistd.h>

       unsigned int sleep(unsigned int seconds);

Comment: May I ask why you want to pause the program? Sometimes, meaningful/better alternatives exist.

Answer (score 29):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello waiter" << std::endl;
    std::chrono::seconds dura( 5);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( dura );
    std::cout << "Waited 5s\n";
}
```

`this_thread::sleep_for` Blocks the execution of the current thread for at least the specified sleep_duration.

Comment: sleep_for is introduced in c++11, if you (have to) use an older compiler you have to use sleep() from the C API

Comment: The question is tagged C++ not C

Comment: @user1595178 And `sleep()` is *not* standard C.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this on the pure C level, because C api calls are usable also from C++. It eliminiates the problem if you actual c++ library didn't contained the needed `std:chrono` or `std::this_thread` (they differ a little bit).

The C api of most OSes contains some like a sleeping function, although it can be also different. For example, on posixen, there is the `sleep()` API call in the standard C library, and you can use this from C++ as well:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
   sleep(5);
   return;
}
```

Or you can use `usleep()` is you want a better precision as seconds. `usleep()` can sleep for microsecond precision.

On windows, you can use the `Sleep(int usec)` call, which is with big '`S`', and uses milliseconds.

Comment: This is **not** standard C. ["In the C and C++ programming languages, unistd.h is the name of the header file that provides access to the POSIX operating system API."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unistd.h) The equivalent standard C function is [`thrd_sleep`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thrd_sleep)

Comment: I think sleep is a POSIX call, not part of the C library. Win32 has Sleep (with capital S) but it takes millisecs.